# Freeing allocated memory from a const pointer

Tags: c, pointers, free

I was given a simple task - to implement a simple Linked List - structure in C.

I have some questions regarding implementation of a function that frees allocated memory (Linked list and Nodes).

These are the structs that I'm using:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    struct Node* next; 
    struct Node* prev; 
    int* data; 
    int len; 
} Node;

typedef struct LinkedList
{
    Node* head;
    Node* tail; 
} LinkedList;
```

As a part of the whole interface that I was asked to implement, I was given the task to implement these methods:

```
void freeLinkedList(LinkedList *const list);

void removeNode(LinkedList *const list, Node *const node);
```

These are my implementations:

```
void freeLinkedList(LinkedList *const list)
{
    if(list == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,NULL_POINTER_ERROR);
        return;
    }
    if (list-> head == NULL || list -> tail == NULL)
    {
        free(list);
        return;
    }
    Node* curr = list -> tail;
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        Node* next = curr -> next;
        free(curr -> data);
        free(curr);
        curr = next;
    }
    free(list);
}


void removeNode(LinkedList *const list, Node *const node)
{
    if (node == NULL || list == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, NULL_POINTER_ERROR);
        return;
    }
    if (list-> head == NULL || list -> tail == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, EMPTY_LINKED_LIST_ERROR);
        return;
    }
    Node* curr = list -> tail;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        if (curr == node)
        {
            if(node == list -> tail && node == list -> head) // Both head and tail
            {
                free(curr -> data);
                free(curr);
                list -> tail = NULL; list -> head = NULL;
                return;
            }
            if(node == list -> tail) // Only tail
            {
                free(curr -> data);
                list -> tail = node -> next;
                free(curr);
                list -> tail -> prev = NULL;
                return;
            }
            if(node == list -> head) // Only head
            {
                free(curr -> data);
                list -> head = node -> prev;
                free(curr);
                list -> head -> next = NULL;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                node -> prev -> next = node -> next;
                node -> next -> prev = node -> prev;
                free(curr -> data);
                free(curr);
                return;
            }
        }
        curr = curr -> next;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, NODE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR);
}
```

As you can see - it's pretty straight forward. I started debugging some tests, and I saw that the pointers aren't changing after the call to `free(ptr)`, I guess that it is something that has to do with the `const` in the functions parameters.

How can I tell if the memory was really freed? Is there an obvious mistake in my implementation? Would love to get some insight.

Comment: `LinkedList *const list` means that `list` will not be changed by the function. Indeed, freeing the _memory_ pointed to be `list` does not change `list`.

Comment: The function `free` doesn't change the value of the pointer, so it is correct behavior if you see the same value for the pointer

Comment: As a matter of style: it is customary in C to write `list -> tail` as `list->tail`, that is, without spaces.

Comment: _How can I tell if the memory was really freed?_ There's no standard way to do that.

Comment: In addition to Sebastian's comment: the memory is freed after a call to `free` (QED). But looking at the pointer won't tell you it was freed. This leaves the caller of your functions the task of not using the list anymore after calling `freeLinkedList`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie So overall, the implementation makes sense?

Comment: I only looked at `freeLinkedList` and that makes sense.

Comment: Suggestion: `if(list == NULL)` then simply return without raising an error. There is just nothing to free.

Comment: Inside the function `freeLinkedList` when you initialize `Node* curr = list -> tail;` I guess you meant `Node* curr = list -> head;`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, Thanks. I was worried because of the debugging itself - I thought that the pointers would point on some sort of garbage after freeing it.

Comment: Suggestion: `if (list-> head == NULL || list -> tail == NULL)` is not really a special case. It will be handled gracefully by the next statements.

Comment: another thing: in function `removeNode`, why do you need to iterate over the list if you already have the pointer to the target node?

Answer (score 0):

Following discussions in the comments, I think `freeLinkedList` can be implemented as:

```
void freeLinkedList(LinkedList *const list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return;

    Node* curr = list->head;
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        Node* next = curr->next;
        free(curr->data);
        free(curr);
        curr = next;
    }
    free(list);
}
```